# Xsl count based on Filtered node

Tags: xslt, foreach, count, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml:

```
<Activity>
     <item>
        <task>XXX</task>
        <assignto>User1</assignto>
     </item>
     <item>
        <task>YYY</task>
        <assignto>User2</assignto>
     </item>
     <item>
        <task>ZZZ</task>
        <assignto>User1</assignto>
     </item>
     <team>
        <member>User1</member>
        <member>User2</member>
     <team>
</Activity>
```

I want to generate using XSL a count of task per member in the team.

User-    Count
user1-     2
user2-     1

so far I have the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <table>
       <tr>
           <th>User</th>
           <th>Task Count</th>
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="Activity/team/member">
          <tr>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="node()" /></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="count(/Activity/item[assignto='user1'])" /></td>
          </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so far I hardcoded 'user1', I would like to filter based on the current member in the for each loop.

Can someone help, please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

here you go, store the member in a variable and test on that variable. You also have an error in your source XML, you need /team.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Task Count</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="Activity/team/member">
                    <xsl:variable name="assignto">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="node()" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="count(/Activity/item[assignto=$assignto])" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

output is:

```
<html>
<body>
  <table>
     <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Task Count</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>User1</td>
        <td>2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>User2</td>
        <td>1</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your reference to `'user1'` with a reference to the current node at the start of the XPath address, which is done using the `current()` function:

```
t:\ftemp>type activity.xml 
<Activity>
     <item>
        <task>XXX</task>
        <assignto>User1</assignto>
     </item>
     <item>
        <task>YYY</task>
        <assignto>User2</assignto>
     </item>
     <item>
        <task>ZZZ</task>
        <assignto>User1</assignto>
     </item>
     <team>
        <member>User1</member>
        <member>User2</member>
     </team>
</Activity>

t:\ftemp>call xslt activity.xml activity.xsl 
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Task Count</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>User1</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>User2</td>
            <td>1</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
t:\ftemp>type activity.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <table>
       <tr>
           <th>User</th>
           <th>Task Count</th>
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="Activity/team/member">
          <tr>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="node()" /></td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="count(/Activity/item[assignto=current()])" /></td>
          </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on the current member, you can just use the "current()" function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/Activity/item[assignto=current()])" />
```

However, you might benefit from using a key here, to make the counting more efficient. First define your key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="assignto" />
```

Then you can write your count like so:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(key('item', .))" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="assignto" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
        <table>
           <tr>
               <th>User</th>
               <th>Task Count</th>
           </tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="Activity/team/member">
              <tr>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="node()" /></td>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('item', .))" /></td>
              </tr>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```